# Toiletries allowed in checked baggage for Turkish Airlines?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, turkey, turkish-airlines, toiletries

The website of Turkish Airlines clearly states that liquids like perfumes, deodorants, face wash and other such stuff are prohibited in the cabin baggage.

If not cabin, is it allowed in the checked baggage?

Comment: Surely this is a duplicate?  I mean, for a seasoned traveler, it's a very basic question, but I find it hard to believe that nobody has asked it here before.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, they're allowed in checked luggage, as toiletries are not on the list of [prohibited luggage](http://www.turkishairlines.com/en-int/travel-information/baggage/dangerous-goods) published by Turkish Airlines.

Comment: However it is important to note that said toiletries need be packaged in appropriately sized containers, depending on the airport. A 1 L bottle of Listerine wont be allowed in cabin luggage in many airports, but a small 100ml bottle will.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Limit is 100ml afaik.